# Will item effects proc on modified Smite?

Tags: league-of-legends

Will items like Liandry and Rylai Scepter proc on Challenging/Chilling Smite since they do inflict damage?

Also will the enemies around the target of the Blasting Smite gets proc of such items?

Comment: I can confirm it procs spell vamp, so it most likely procs every every effect as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smite and Chilling smite counts as a single target spell and will thus behave like one. This means it will apply a Rylai's slow, Spellvamp and any other spell-based effects however this also means that it can be blocked by Spellshields.

Challenging smite will not apply any Spell vamp or a Rylai's slow if it's applied to a champion since it only debuffs the target and doesn't deal direct damage to it. But once again this will be blocked by spellshield.

Blasting smite works exactly the same as the normal or chilling one but it has reduced spell effects. The slow will be reduced to 15% and the spell vamp to 33% of it's initial value.

Comment: Don't modified smites deal true damage? Those items only proc on magic damage

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Yes smite always deals True damage but Spellvamp procs from **damage dealt by spells** which can be magic, physical or true and Rylai's procs off damage dealing spells.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill just like Ahri's orb coming back, it deals true damage but still spellvamp(from items not only from her innate ability)

Comment: There is a way to make it proc on Smite, by getting a Luden's Echo. Luden's proc on spells (including smite, like Spell Vamp). The Luden's proc is magic damage, and thus would then apply both Rylay's and Liandray's